# Accessing Object properties

Tags: apex, code

When accessing Object properties like 'Account.Name' multiple times throughout the code, is it better to create a variable and assign the property value to the variable **once** or is it fine to continuously reference the same property throughout the code? See example for more detail:

```
if(Account.Name.equals('Ben')) 
    Account.Status = 'Open';
else if(Account.Name.equals('Sim'))
    Account.Status = 'Closed';

Case.Name = Account.Name;
Opportunity.Newest = Account.Name;
```

As you can see above, the same 'Account.Name' property is accessed multiple times. Is it more **efficient** to do something like:

```
String accountName = Account.Name;

if(accountName.equals('Ben')) 
    Account.Status = 'Open';
else if(accountName.equals('Sim'))
    Account.Status = 'Closed';

Case.Name = accountName;
Opportunity.Newest = accountName;
```

Comment: I do not see a reason to be more efficient to create a variable. Thinking, could be less, as you are creating more one variable.

Answer (score 5):

It is (or, at least, used to be) faster to use a variable if you're going to use the field lots of times. See this video for lots of experimentation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6QnalRWlEE

Measured time on Salesforce will change as the compiler changes, and server load changes. So, unless you measure carefully, you might not even be able to see the difference.

**Warning: opinion coming...**

I would always treat code cleanliness (is it easy to read?) as more important than performance until you run into an actual performance problem. To quote Knuth:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying
>   about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these
>   attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when
>   debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that
>   critical 3%.

However, introducing an extra variable can help with cleanliness because it gives you a chance to give that variable a descriptive name which makes the code easier to follow.

Personally, that's why I'd use the extra variable.

Comment: +1 While caching a field value is rarely worth it from a performance perspective, developers should be mindful of other types of variables. For example, if you get a value from a map and you plan on using it a lot, you can save significant CPU time. In all other cases, it's more of a legibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

There could be minor efficiency improvement, but IMO more of coding cleaness as Aidan mentioned already.

This is what I will code below. If more conditions are coming, a `switch statement` might fit better, or using base class and inherited class for polymorphism to scape from condition check.

```
String accountName = Account.Name;


if(accountName == 'Ben'){ 
    Account.Status = 'Open';
} else if(accountName == 'Sim'){
    Account.Status = 'Closed';
}

Case.Name = accountName;
Opportunity.Newest = accountName;
```